# Storyboard.SetTarget vs Storyboard.SetTargetName

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

Why does Storyboard.SetTargetName works but Storyboard.SetTarget does not?
Here xaml -

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ClipToBounds="True">
        <X:SmartContentControl  x:Name="smartContent"  Content="{Binding Path=MainContent}" ContentChanging="smartContent_ContentChanging">
            <X:SmartContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransformNew" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </X:SmartContentControl.RenderTransform>
        </X:SmartContentControl>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=smartContent, Path=LastImage}">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransformLast" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

Here C#

```
private void smartContent_ContentChanging(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, -smartContent.RenderSize.Width, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)));
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation(smartContent.RenderSize.Width, 0.0, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)));

    doubleAnimation1.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
    doubleAnimation2.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
    storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation1);
    storyBoard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation2);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation1, this.translateTransformLast); //--- this does not work
    //Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation1, "translateTransformLast"); -- this works
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation2, this.translateTransformNew);//--- this does not work
    //Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation2, "translateTransformNew"); -- this works
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
    if (smartContent.LastImage != null)
        storyBoard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found answer here!
[Why don't these animations work when I'm using a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338714/why-dont-these-animations-work-when-im-using-a-storyboard)

Storyboard cant animate TranslateTransform, since it is not UIElement.
This is how i do it now! :)

```
  Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation1, this.lastImage);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation2, this.smartContent);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
```

Comment: Not so easy if your transform is part of a transform group.  It looks like you found a legitimate bug (I've just bumped into it myself). http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723701/storyboard-settarget-only-works-on-uielements-but-throws-no-exception

Comment: If you are part of the group, you need to hit the children of the group, and order is important:  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translatex, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[1].X"));