# WPF Margin Thickness

Tags: wpf, animation, width, margin, stackpanel

Background:
I'm loading images into a Stack Panel (called MainStack) displayed horizontally (for argument sake, 10 images) with only room for 4 images in view. As I load the images from the List I'm setting the width of each to 300 so they're all in the same size box.

I want to move the images from right to left using the Stack Panel's Margin (left) property. I want the appearance of scrolling left by exactly the same amount of the width of each image (looped with 4 second delay) until the last image is in view. Here's my code for the Margin animation:

```
    Dim result As New Storyboard
    Dim animation As New ThicknessAnimation
    animation.From = MainStack.Margin
    animation.EasingFunction = New PowerEase() With {.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut, .Power = 3}
    animation.To = New Thickness(-300, 0, 0, 0)
    animation.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, MainStack)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, New PropertyPath("Margin"))
    result.Children.Add(animation)
    result.Begin()
```

Strange thing is happening. The Stack Panel is moving to the left but only by about half the width of the image.

What is going on?!?

/* edit */
As per H.B. suggestion, I've tried to implement a TranslateTransform but not having much success.

Can anyone see any problems with this code?

```
    Dim translatePosition = New Point(300, 0)

    RenderTransform = New TranslateTransform()
    Dim d As New Duration(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 30))
    Dim x As New DoubleAnimation(translatePosition.X, d)

    Storyboard.SetTarget(x, MainStack)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(x, New PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"))

    Dim sb As New Storyboard()
    sb.Children.Add(x)
    sb.Begin()
```

Nothing seems to be happening.
Ben

Comment: Why not apply a TranslateTransform and animate that instead?

Comment: Hi H.B. Thanks for the comment, I'm looking into it. Are you able to suggest any code that I can use? I'm reading TranslateTransform doesn't place nicely with Storyboard.

Comment: That's news to me, who says that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957582/wpf-storyboard-settarget-vs-storyboard-settargetname

Comment: Something to do with it not being a UIElement

Comment: Well, you only have one animation, hence you do not need a Storyboard anyway, just use `BeginAnimation` on the transform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try putting your entire stackpanel in a canvas and just animating the Canvas.Left property to scroll the images.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you is to use a horizontal ListBox, then you can animate the ScrollViewer.  If you want to try it this way, here's a link that may help:  [WPF - Animate ListBox.ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665719/wpf-animate-listbox-scrollviewer-horizontaloffset).